# React: Infinite function call loop after Slider onChangeEnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, slider

When I change the value of my slider, it should call a function `onChangeEnd`. However, when this occurs, the `calculateEvent` function is called in an infinite loop. This continues forever, even as I keep moving my slider around afterwards. Why does this happen?

```js
var yearStart = 0;
var yearEnd = 50;
var years : number[] = [];
while(yearStart < yearEnd+1){
    years.push(yearStart++);
}
const xAxis : number[] = years;

const Savings = () => {

    const [initialSavings, setInitialSavings] = React.useState<string>("5000");
    const [monthlyDepo, setMonthlyDepo] = React.useState<string>("100");
    const [interestRate, setInterestRate] = React.useState<number>(2);
    const [yAxis, setYAxis] = React.useState<number[]>([]);

    const handleChange = useCallback((newValue) => {
        setInterestRate(newValue);
      }, []);

    const calculateEvent = useCallback((event : string, slider : number, option : number) => {
        switch(option) {
            case 1:
              setInitialSavings(event);
              break;
            case 2:
              setMonthlyDepo(event);
              break;
            case 3:
              setInterestRate(slider);
          }
        console.log("Calculate event called with slider value: ", interestRate);
        getProjection(initialSavings, monthlyDepo, interestRate).then((m) => {
            console.log(m);
            setYAxis(m);
        })
    }, [initialSavings, monthlyDepo, interestRate]);

    return(
    <DefaultLayout>
        <Container pt={6}>
            <VStack spacing={4}>
                <Heading as="h1">Interest Rate Calculator</Heading>
                <Heading as="h4">{initialSavings}, {monthlyDepo}, {interestRate}</Heading>
                <Input 
                    label="Initial Savings amount" 
                    name="Initial Savings" 
                    onInput={e => calculateEvent(e.currentTarget.value, 0, 1)} 
                    placeholder="5000"
                />
                <Input 
                    label="Monthly Deposit" 
                    name="Monthly Deposit" 
                    onInput={e => calculateEvent(e.currentTarget.value, 0, 2)} 
                    placeholder="100"
                />
                <Slider
                    label="Interest Rate"
                    name="Interest Rate"
                    value={interestRate}
                    min={1}
                    max={15}
                    step={1}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    onChangeEnd={e => calculateEvent("", e, 3)} 
                    focusThumbOnChange={false}
                    role="group"
                    onFocus={(e) => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }}
                />
                <LineChart
                    title="Savings Over time"
                    xAxisData={xAxis}
                    yAxisData={yAxis}
                    xLabel="Years"
                    yLabel="Amount"
                />
            </VStack>
        </Container>
    </DefaultLayout>
    )
}
```

Comment: It looks like your args are in the wrong order.  The function takes `(event, slider, option)` but you are passing `event` second in `e => calculateEvent("", e, 3)`

Comment: Well actually now I see that you want to `event` to be a `string` and I have no idea what type `e` is in the `onChangeEnd` callback because I don't know what `Slider` is.  Please update your post to include the imports of package components.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you are getting a loop. However, I think you should breakup calculateEvent() into 3 separate functions instead of using a switch statement and option arg. Doing so may help you identify the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, heres what I propose.

Let's break that `calculateEvent` function up into its separate components.

Then, let's create a `useEffect` callback that will re-calculate the projection, whenever our inputs change. I'd prefer to do this on render, but we are stuck with an effect because `getProjection` returns a promise.

Now, I understand why you want to use the `onChangeEnd` event. `getProjection()` is expensive, and so you only want to call it, when the user has finished choosing a value.

So let's break it up into two states. One state to manage the slider value. And then a second state to hold the actual `interestRate` value. We will wait to update the `interestRate` value until `onChangeEnd` is called.

Also, let's make sure to control those inputs by putting values on them, and using onChange instead of onInput.

```js
var yearStart = 0;
var yearEnd = 50;
var years: number[] = [];
while (yearStart < yearEnd + 1) {
  years.push(yearStart++);
}
const xAxis: number[] = years;

const Savings = () => {
  const [initialSavings, setInitialSavings] = React.useState<string>('5000');
  const [monthlyDepo, setMonthlyDepo] = React.useState<string>('100');
  const [interestRate, setInterestRate] = React.useState<number>(2);
  const [interestRateSlider, setInterestRateSlider] = React.useState<number>(2);
  const [yAxis, setYAxis] = React.useState<number[]>([]);

  const handleSavingsChange = (e) => {
    setInitialSavings(e.target.value);
  }

  const handleMonthlyDepoChange = (e) => {
    setMonthlyDepo(e.target.value);
  }

  const handleInterestRateSliderChange = (value) => {
    setInterestRateSlider(value);
  };

  const handleInterestRateSliderChangeEnd = (value) => {
    setInterestRate(value)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getProjection(initialSavings, monthlyDepo, interestRate).then((m) => {
      setYAxis(m);
    });
  },[initialSavings, monthlyDepo, interestRate])

  return (
    <DefaultLayout>
      <Container pt={6}>
        <VStack spacing={4}>
          <Heading as="h1">Interest Rate Calculator</Heading>
          <Heading as="h4">
            {initialSavings}, {monthlyDepo}, {interestRate}
          </Heading>
          <Input
            label="Initial Savings amount"
            name="Initial Savings"
            value={initialSavings}
            onChange={handleSavingsChange}
            placeholder="5000"
          />
          <Input
            label="Monthly Deposit"
            name="Monthly Deposit"
            value={monthlyDepo}
            onChange={handleMonthlyDepoChange}
            placeholder="100"
          />
          <Slider
            label="Interest Rate"
            name="Interest Rate"
            value={interestRate}
            min={1}
            max={15}
            step={1}
            onChange={handleInterestRateSliderChange}
            onChangeEnd={handleInterestRateSliderChangeEnd}
            focusThumbOnChange={false}
            role="group"
            onFocus={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
            }}
          />
          <LineChart
            title="Savings Over time"
            xAxisData={xAxis}
            yAxisData={yAxis}
            xLabel="Years"
            yLabel="Amount"
          />
        </VStack>
      </Container>
    </DefaultLayout>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I think separating the SliderValue and InterestRate value while also using the `useEffect` functionality made everything work well!